# BSOD on a new built PC during Windows 10 installation

Tags: windows-10, usb, bsod, windows-installation

I just bought a brand new build PC. Whenever I try to install Windows 10 with a USB drive, it basically can't boot that installation progress. I choose the UEFI option to boot my USB, then ASUS logo and sometimes Windows logo appear with loading icon below starting to spin but after half a second, I get a BSOD says a *stop code* called "APCI_BIOS_ERROR" and it reboots my PC.

**My PC Specs:**

- Asus Prime B450-M K Motherboard
- Ryzen 5 2500X Processor
- Adata XPG 3000Mhz DDR4 8GB RAM
- Toshiba TR200 480GB SSD
- Asus ROG Strix RX570 GPU
- Cooler Master Elite V3 600W PSU

By the way, there was an update for my BIOS, and yes I updated it but the result stays the same. I also **replaced my RAM in each slot** but it didn't do any good. And I tested my RAM with Memtest86, **0 errors found**.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: In order to better identify your problem, are you receiving `APCI_BIOS_ERROR` or `APCI_BIOS_FATAL_ERROR`?

Comment: @Ramhound it is merely `APCI_BIOS_ERROR`

Comment: I brought the case with me to the shop where I bought it. They found that the motherboard was the fault. They replaced with a new one, and haha! It works now.